# Twitter bootstrap form layout single line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have this form.

```
<form id="chartTimeRangeOptions">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Chart Time</legend>
                     <label>Start time</label><input type="text" style="width : auto"><br/> 
                     <label>End time</label><input type="text" style="width : auto"> <br/>
                     <button class="btn btn-small btn-info">Apply</button>
                </fieldset>
</form>
```

which looks like this,

[image]

And I want to show it like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the "form-inline" class.  This should get you where you want to be...

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Thanks.Should have checked documentation first !